# Grails Mail service not working with guartz scheduler in war mode

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

I send a mail at a specific time using quartz scheduler :

```
static triggers = {
   cron name: 'DashboardReporting', cronExpression:"0 0 11,20 * * ?"
}
```

Now inside execute I send the mail using grails async plugin which works perfectly under run-app mode:

```
emailNotificationService.sendDashboardReportEmail(emaiListing, [model:model,XYZmodel:XYZmodel])
```

Now this thing works perfectly when I do run-app for development purposes and sends mail from my local machine.

But when I run the same code using run-war I get this exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3042)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$PageRenderRequestCreator.createInstance(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:198)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$PageRenderRequestCreator$createInstance.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.init(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:147)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.this$2$init(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$RenderEnvironment.with(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:178)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:148)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer.render(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:63)
at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$render.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailMessageBuilder.doRender(AsynchronousMailMessageBuilder.groovy:281)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailMessageBuilder.html(AsynchronousMailMessageBuilder.groovy:267)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1119)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService$_sendMultipleMail_closure3.doCall(EmailNotificationService.groovy:32)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService$_sendMultipleMail_closure3.doCall(EmailNotificationService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService.sendAsynchronousMail(AsynchronousMailService.groovy:21)
at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a38fa914.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3608bbae.sendAsynchronousMail(<generated>)
at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService$sendAsynchronousMail.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:82)
at AsynchronousMailGrailsPlugin$_configureSendMail_closure9.doCall(AsynchronousMailGrailsPlugin.groovy:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:248)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService.sendMultipleMail(EmailNotificationService.groovy:29)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService.this$2$sendMultipleMail(EmailNotificationService.groovy)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService$this$2$sendMultipleMail$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService.sendDashboardReportEmail(EmailNotificationService.groovy:51)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c42786d4.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c078a16e.sendDashboardReportEmail(<generated>)
at com.pcjoshi.om.EmailNotificationService$sendDashboardReportEmail.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
at com.pcjoshi.om.DashboarReportingJob.execute(DashboarReportingJob.groovy:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

I have used the default quartz version provided by the async. Also a thing of note is I cound not directly inject the async mail service so I autowired it with :

```
 @Autowired
AsynchronousMailService asyncMailService
```

But again this thing is working fine with run-app and under other many usage of the service, only in war mode this error surfaces.

I also tried the normal mail plugin but had the same problem. Any suggestions guys ??

Comment: in your `Config.groovy` (or an external file if externalized config is used), is the `grails.serverURL` property set?

Comment: I don't know how that should help in my context ??? But then no it's not set in external config or config.groovy.

Comment: Because the NPE is caused by Grails unable to determine the server's URL. Just check the source code at `grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$PageRenderRequestCreator.createInstance(MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy:198)`

Comment: Great point out, thanks. But I believe such information must have been mentioned in the documentation. I mean I nearly ditched async mail service for an alternative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is already a bit older, but the answer provided does not work for me in grails 3.0.9. Specifically, it would require me to set a global serverUrl that overrides anything specified for any of the development/testing/production environments.

The below, added to BootStrap.groovy does the trick. It seems that the LinkGenerator initialization in grails is actually the culprit, rather than the mail plugin.

```
LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("grailsLinkGenerator")
grailsLinkGenerator.configuredServerBaseURL = 
                    grailsLinkGenerator.configuredServerBaseURL ?:
                         grailsApplication.config.grails.serverUrl
```

Comment: I was having this problem with an integration test, but putting this line into the `setup()` method worked a treat.

Comment: I was ran into this issue when upgrading to 3.1.6 and this fixed my issue as well.  Many thanks.